# Error running pod install for an update due to permissions

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods, rbenv, rbenv-gemset

I am getting an error when running `pod install` on my project. The error is seen as a permission error:

```
Errno::EACCES - Permission denied - 
/Users/**/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1406:in `unlink'
/Users/**/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1406:in `block in remove_file'
```

RBENV version
rbenv 0.4.0-49-g8b04303

Ruby version
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]

Running `sudo pod install` would work fine. What should I do to correct the permission error so that `pod install` can be run as normal?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` path/to/project/
```

if that doesn't help, you can also try

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.cocoapods
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
```

Comment: Thanks it was specifically the first line that resolved this for me.

Comment: First line for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately these steps didn't work for me and I resolve with:

```
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/*
```